# Issue using apache commons optimize() in java

Tags: java, optimization, apache-commons

I am currently trying to implement a no-derivative multivariate optimization in java using the apache library. However, I am having trouble providing the required "OptimizationData" to the optimize() method. Below is what I have so far for running my optimization.

```
public static double[] Optimize(double[][] contractDataMatrix, double[] modelData,String modelType,String weightType){
    ObjectiveFunction objective = new      
ObjectiveFunction(contractDataMatrix,modelType,weightType);

    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer optimizer =new   
org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer(.01,.001);
    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction obj = new    
org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction(objective);



    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair finalData=optimizer.optimize(
    new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval(200),
    obj,
    GoalType.MINIMIZE,
    new InitialGuess(modelData)
    );

    return finalData.getPoint();

}
```

First I create an ObjectiveFunction, which is a class I made as a wrapper of the apache ObjectiveFunction class that extends it. I did this because the objective function is itself a function of several arguments, which are not of import to my question. Then I contruct a SimplexOptimizer and try to call optimize() on it following an example I found online. Though the docs do not say clearly what is required as input, I believe I have provided all necessary arguments, with one possible exception which I discuss in the edit below. Anyways, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NullArgumentException: null is not     allowed
at   org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer.checkParameters(SimplexOptimizer.java:214)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer.doOptimize(SimplexOptimizer.java:128)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer.doOptimize(SimplexOptimizer.java:89)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseOptimizer.optimize(BaseOptimizer.java:154)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseMultivariateOptimizer.optimize(BaseMultivariateOptimizer.java:66)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateOptimizer.optimize(MultivariateOptimizer.java:64)
at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer.optimize(SimplexOptimizer.java:122)
at compfin3.CompFin3.Optimize(CompFin3.java:181)
at compfin3.CompFin3.main(CompFin3.java:118)
Java Result: 1
```

Does anyone have any idea what "null" value this error refers to, and how I might fix it?

Best,

Paul

EDIT:
I believe I have tracked down the source of the problem. It appears that as a part of my optimization data that I pass to the optimizer, I was forgetting to define the specific AbstractSimplex I am using. Unfortunately, none of the constructors given in the docs actually work. When I try

```
org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair finalData=optimizer.optimize(
    new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval(200),
    obj,
    GoalType.MINIMIZE,
    new InitialGuess(modelData),
    new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.AbstractSimplex(2)
    );
```

I get the compile error

```
 AbstractSimplex is abstract, cannot be instantiated
```

even though this is one of the documented constructors for that class.

Comment: I would recommend putting that in an answer and marking it as "accepted" so that future visitors with similar issues will quickly see it.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, I will do that as soon as the question is answered. But I still have not figured out how to properly pass an AbstractSimplex as an argument, or gotten any advice as to where there things are accurately documented.

Comment: Since `AbstracSimplex` is abstract and cannot be instantiated, you could use a class that is known to directly inherit from it (that in itself is not abstract) - check the API docs for options: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/nonlinear/scalar/noderiv/AbstractSimplex.html

Comment: Thank you, I have added my updated code as an answer. I am now having issues with the maximum number of iterations being exceeded, but since this specific question is answered I will call the issue resolved. By the way, I assumed that the dimension of the simplex should be equal to the number of parameters... is there any reason why it would be any different?

Answer (score 1):

The folllowing code resolved my issue:

```
public static double[] Optimize(double[][] contractDataMatrix,double[] minData, double[] maxData,double[] modelData,String modelType,String weightType){
    ObjectiveFunction objective = new     ObjectiveFunction(contractDataMatrix,modelType,weightType);

    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer optimizer =new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.SimplexOptimizer(.01,.001);
    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction obj = new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction(objective);

    int n = modelData.length;

    org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair finalData=optimizer.optimize(
    new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval(200),
    obj,
    GoalType.MINIMIZE,
    new InitialGuess(modelData),
    new org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.NelderMeadSimplex(n)
    );

    return finalData.getPoint();

}
```